# How to speed up custom QSortFilterProxyModel?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, qsortfilterproxymodel

I've got a custom QSortFilterProxyModel that enables filtering on all except columns specified in list that can be set via function. I override *filterAcceptsRow()* function to fetch rows with filter pattern. Everything works fine, it filters correctly as I wanted but it takes more time to filter in custom model than it does in standard model.

I tried only two different approaches to match model data with filter pattern (as commented in code below), but both of them are slower than using standard model. I also tried to change type of data received from model index to QString as in original method of standard model:
https://dreamswork.github.io/qt4/classQSortFilterProxyModel.html#acb9addede0e557d21031132712bd0528

but there is a general problem of converting pythonic string/unicode to QString data type.
I use Python in version 2.7 and PyQt4 - there is no option (for now) to use higher version of Python/PyQt.

```py
class MultiColsSortFilterProxyModel(QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    """
    Custom QSortFilterProxyModel with possibility to
    disable given columns from model filtering
    """
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MultiColsSortFilterProxyModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ex_cols = []

    def set_excluded_cols(self, ex_cols):
        """
        Sets list with columns indexes that will be excluded
        from model filtering
        :param ex_cols: List<int> list of columns to exclude
        """
        self.ex_cols = ex_cols

    def excluded_cols(self):
        """
        Gets columns indexes excluded from model filtering
        :return: List<int>
        """
        return self.ex_col

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, source_row, source_parent):
        """
        Reimplemented from QSortFilterProxyModel.filterAcceptsRow()
        Works almost the same, but exclude setted columns from filtering
        """
        pattern = self.filterRegExp().pattern()
        if self.filterRegExp().isEmpty():
            return True
        if self.filterKeyColumn() == -1:
            col_count = self.sourceModel().columnCount()
            for col in xrange(col_count):
                if col not in self.ex_cols:
                    index = self.sourceModel().index(source_row, col, source_parent)
                    value = unicode(self.sourceModel().data(index))
                    # if self.filterRegExp().indexIn(value) >= 0:
                    if value.__contains__(pattern):
                        return True
            return False
        index = self.sourceModel().index(source_row, self.filterKeyColumn(), source_parent)
        if not index.isValid():
            return True
        value = unicode(self.sourceModel().data(index))
        return value.__contains__(pattern)
        # return self.filterRegExp().indexIn(value) >= 0
```

While on standard model, when I type some text in filter field, it filters in a blink of an eye, but when I switch to custom model, when I type, it takes time to even show in field what I just typed. It also gets slower and slower with bigger row number (from few up to tens of thousands).

Comment: It could help to know what your "custom model" does. Also, since you're stuck with Python2/PyQt4 (I've the same problem) I suggest you to use sip API version 2 for QString at least: before importing PyQt do `import sip` and `sip.setapi('QString', 2)`. This will allow you to transparently use/get python [unicode] strings wherever a QString is normally expected/returned; you will not be able to import `QtCore.QString`s and use their methods, but it will be a huge advantage.

Comment: Check [Qt.py](https://github.com/mottosso/Qt.py): it's a "compatibility layer" around all Qt bindings which by default sets sip API v.2 to all types (saving you the mess of toPyObject() of QVariants too) and can help you write code that will make a future transition to python3/PyQt5 (or PySide) much easier. You'll need to make some find/replace of module names (all widget classes have been moved from QtGui to QtWidgets) and manually import some things from PyQt4, but once you've got that everything will be ok. Just ensure to `os.environ['QT_PREFERRED_BINDING'] = 'PyQt4'` before everything.

Comment: Thanks for advices :) my model is used to show data from sqlite spatial table in QTableView, where I can edit/delete object attributes and show it on map, so nothing too complicated. I left this issue for now, when transition to python3/PyQt5 will happen, then I'll get back to this.

Comment: You misunderstood me. We don't need to know what your model is for, but what actually (as in programmatically) does: if the proxy works fine for standard models and not your custom one, it's likely that the issue is in the latter, and you can't expect us to guess what it does if you don't share that code also.

Comment: Maybe I wrote it wrong: by standard model I mean default QSortFilterProxyModel and by custom model I mean the one that is shown above (MultiColsSortFilterProxyModel). Model that contains data is a QSqlQueryModel that fetches data from SQLite database. If I'm still getting it wrong, please tell me.

Comment: It's possible that the slowness depends on the size of your source model (in columns and records); does it have thousands of records? For starters, I'd suggest you to use Qt implementation anytime it's possible: in your case, just check against `self.filterRegExp().indexIn(self.sourceModel().index(source_row, column, source_parent)) >= 0`, which will speed up things. For future reference, remember that using "standard model" might be misleading, as it's common to use it as referred to Qt's QStandardItemModel; maybe it's better to say, for example, "proxy model default implementation/behavior".